# Flycheck stopped checking after the installation of rtags and cmake-ide

Tags: flycheck

First I had flycheck and it worked just fine for my C projects. At the time, I was having a problem with my init file. I even posted about it. I was using an org file as my config file (using org-babel) and I accidentally used `#+END_SRC emacs-lisp` and it confused the interpreter.

After correcting that problem, I have decided to install `cmake-ide` and wrote some basic configs that can be found [here](https://github.com/mrisso/dotfiles). After that, my flycheck began to  prompt an error that said

> Error while checking syntax automatically: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)

Then I read some parts of the documentations for cmake-ide and rtags and I discovered that I had to compile some parts of rtags that were not written in lisp. After the compilation, that flycheck error just magically disappears but it does not check for errors. I don't know if cmake-ide is configuring it the wrong way or if it is something else I'm missing.

Edit: I was using my config file on another computer and I just couldn't install rtags, so I removed it (and also `cmake-ide`). After that, flycheck just works normally. I wonder what configs I'm missing.

Does `cmake-ide` create some wrong configs for flycheck if I'm not on a cmake project?